# Term for double meanings

Tags: phrases

What is the term used for a phrase that could have more than one meaning such as "This battery is free of charge"?

Answer (score 6):

[Ambiguity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ambiguous):

> - the characteristic of having more than one possible interpretation or meaning (AHD)

[Amphibology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amphibology):

> - a sentence or phrase (as “nothing is good enough for you”) that can be interpreted in more than one way. (M-W)
> - the use of ambiguous phrases or such as can be construed in two senses. A good example is Shakespeare's *'The duke yet lives that Henry shall depose'* (Henry VI).( Chambers's Twentieth Century Dictionary)

Etymology:

> - Gr. *amfibolos*  ambiguous + *logos* speech.

Comment: Hmmm.  Amphibology is one I'd never heard before.  (Now to see if I can remember it next time I need it.)

Comment: @HotLicks Sounds like surgery to me. 'No, you're not amputating my bology - not on your life'.

Comment: @WS2 - Sounds like a frog to me.

Answer (score 4):

- **Double entendre:** a word, phrase, etc, that can be interpreted in two ways, esp one having one meaning that is indelicate
- **Pun:** a play on words, sometimes on different senses of the same word and sometimes on the similar sense or sound of different words.
- **Play of words:** a pun or the act of punning

Comment: I know the 3rd example as "play *on* words" (I'm from US Midwest).

Comment: _play on words_ also suggests that the ambiguity is used in a humorous way.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'm from eastern England and I too know the third example as a *play on words* - I think most people do.

Comment: None of your examples are, in my view, particularly apt to the example sentence given. The first is normally used to describe an indecorous joke, the second and third a smart-Alec witticism. The case in question is a straightforward accidental ***ambiguity***.

Answer (score 4):

Ambiguous means that a phrase can have more than one meaning

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambiguous

Does this help.